# Checking for same values in two arrays

Tags: java, matrix, random, coordinates

I need to make a method, which gets two arrays (same length), and their values represent the x axis and y axis coordinates of a 2d matrix. I need to check for duplicate entries of the same point (x and y are the same).

The idea of the program is: a random matrix is generated with coins represented with 1 and 0. The user inputs the size of the square matrix. Then he inputs the number of points he will try to guess in the matrix that contain the value 1.

I have to check for duplicate entries of the same x and y axis (same points) so that the user cannot get points for "finding" the same coin twice or more times.. I currently have all the coordinates in two separate array.. If there is a better way for me to do this check it would be great :) pls help

```
import java.util.Random; import java.util.Scanner;

public class myClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner vhod = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter dimension: ");
        int dimenzija = vhod.nextInt(), vrednost=0;

        char[][] polje = generirajMatriko(dimenzija);
        izrisMatrike(polje);

        //finding the sum of all coins values
        for(int i=0; i<dimenzija; i++)
            for(int j=0; j<dimenzija; j++)
                if(polje[i][j]=='z')
                    vrednost += 2;
                else if(polje[i][j]=='s')
                    vrednost += 1;


        System.out.print("\nTočke: " + vrednost);

        System.out.print("\nVnesi število točk, ki jih boš iskal: ");
        int st_tock = vhod.nextInt(), x, y, vrednost_najdenih=0;

        int[] xsi = new int[st_tock];
        int[] yni = new int[st_tock];

        for(int i=0; i<st_tock; i++) {
            System.out.print("\nVnesi stolpec " + (i+1) + ". točke: ");
            x = vhod.nextInt();
            xsi[i] = x;
            if(x>dimenzija) {
                System.out.print("\nZaključili ste z igro in izgubili vse kovance!");
                vrednost_najdenih = 0;
                break;
            }
            System.out.print("Vnesi vrstico " + (i+1) + ". točke: ");
            y = vhod.nextInt();
            yni[i] = y;
            if(y>dimenzija) {
                System.out.print("\nZaključili ste z igro in izgubili vse kovance!");
                vrednost_najdenih = 0;
                break;
            }
            else {
                if(polje[y-1][x-1]=='z')
                    vrednost_najdenih += 2;
                else if(polje[y-1][x-1]=='s')
                    vrednost_najdenih += 1;
            }
        }       //ČE STA TA X IN TA Y ŽE BILA V KOMBINACIJI VNEŠENA IN GA NE ŠTEJE... POGOJ PRED PRIŠTEVANJEM?..MORA SHRANJEVATI ELEMENTE V NPR     2     POLJA..X-SI IN Y-NI
        System.out.print("\nVrednost najdenih kovancev: " + vrednost_najdenih);
    }

    static char[][] generirajMatriko(int dimenzija) {
        char[] kovanci = {'z', 's', 'o'};
        char[][] polje = new char[dimenzija][dimenzija];

        //deklaracija randoma
        Random rand = new Random();

        for(int i=0; i<dimenzija; i++)
            for(int j=0; j<dimenzija; j++)
                polje[i][j] = kovanci[rand.nextInt(kovanci.length)];

        //vračanje te matrike glavnemu programu
        return polje;
    }

    static void izrisMatrike(char[][] polje) {
        //izpis matrike
        System.out.print("Generirana matrika: \n");
        for(int i=0; i<polje.length; i++) {
            for(int j=0; j<polje.length; j++) {
                System.out.print("" + polje[i][j]);
                if(j!=((polje.length)-1)) //brez izpisa presledka na koncu vrstice
                    System.out.print(" ");
            }
            if(i!=((polje.length)-1)) //brez izpisa nove vrstice ob koncu izpisa matrike          //RAZMISLI, KER TO DRUGJE NIMAŠ-.-
                System.out.print("\n");
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: is this an assignment ? where is your code ?

Comment: Show your code that is already implemented and then ask what can be wrong, this looks like homework that you want to be resolved.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). From that second link: "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."

Comment: its pasted but its mostly in slovene

Answer (score 1):

Instead of storing coordinates in two separate arrays, you use a class Point which holds both x and y. If you don't want to write your own, you could use:

```
import java.awt.Point;
```

Then you simply use a `Set<Point>` to hold all your unique points.

```
    Set<Point> xsiyni = new HashSet<>();
```

Duplicates can be detected easily... just be sure the Point class implements `equals` and `hashCode` methods or this won't work.

```
    Point p = new Point(x,y);
    if(!xsiyni.add(p)) {
        System.out.println("duplicate");
    }
```

Object oriented design is the Java way.

Comment: Background for this good suggestion: [Anti-pattern: parallel collections](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/06/03/anti-pattern-parallel-collections/).